# How do I get a specific element from a bs4.element.ResultSet?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

I am trying to select a specific element from a particular bs4.element.ResultSet.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
CompanyNOT = "apple"

url = "https://www.annualreports.com/Companies?search="
page_to_scrape = requests.get(url+CompanyNOT)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.content,"html.parser")
urls = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

which gives me an output of:

```
[<a href="/"><img alt="AnnualReports.com" src="/img/ar/logo.webp"/></a>,
 <a href="javascript:;">BROWSE BY</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Exchange">Exchanges</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Industry">Industry</a>,
 <a href="/Search">Other Filters</a>,
 <a href="javascript:;">BROWSE BY</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Exchange">Exchanges</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Industry">Industry</a>,
 <a href="/Search">Other Filters</a>,
 <a href="/Cart"><img alt="" src="/img/ar/cart.webp"/></a>,
 <a href="/Company/apple-hospitality-reit-inc">Apple Hospitality REIT Inc</a>,
 <a class="addbtn" company_id="6874" href="">Request</a>,
 <a href="/Company/apple-inc">Apple Inc.</a>,
 <a href="/Company/maui-land-pineapple-co-inc">Maui Land &amp; Pineapple Co. Inc.</a>,
 <a href="/Company/pineapple-energy-inc">Pineapple Energy Inc.</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Exchange">Exchanges</a>,
 <a href="/Browse/Industry">Industry</a>,
 <a href="/Search">More Filters</a>,
 <a href="/">AnnualReports.com</a>,
 <a href="/">Home</a>,
 <a href="/About">About</a>,
 <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>,
 <a href="/FAQ">FAQs</a>,
 <a href="/Disclaimer">Legal</a>,
 <a href="https://www.irsolutions.com">Visit IR Solutions</a>,
 <a href="/AddCompany">Add My Company</a>]
```

How would I from this be able to extract all the elements with "/Company" in them?

So I would like something like: [/Company/apple-hospitality-reit-inc, /Company/apple-in, /Company/maui-land-pineapple-co-inc,  /Company/pineapple-energy-inc]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector API:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.annualreports.com/Companies?search=apple"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a[href*="/Company/"]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/Company/apple-hospitality-reit-inc
/Company/apple-inc
/Company/maui-land-pineapple-co-inc
/Company/pineapple-energy-inc
```

---

Or `bs4` API:

```py
for a in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and '/Company/' in tag.get('href', '')):
    print(a['href'])
```

---

Or: select all `<a>` tags and filter it in list-comprehension:

```py
hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a') if '/Company/' in a.get('href', '')]
print(*hrefs, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I would like something like: [/Company/apple-hospitality-reit-inc, /Company/apple-in, /Company/maui-land-pineapple-co-inc, /Company/pineapple-energy-inc]

Using [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors-through-the-css-property) with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
company_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href*="\/Company\/"]')]
```

You can do it with `find_all` as well, with a [`lambda`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function) expression for the `href` argument, but it feels a bit more clunky to me:

```py
company_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda h: h and '/Company/' in h)]
```

---

Of course, you can also filter the list comprehension with an `if` instead of using `lambda` in the `find_all`

```py
company_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if '/Company/' in a['href']]
```

which is the same as

```py
company_urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a[href]') if '/Company/' in a['href'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for `<a>`-tags that simply *have* an `href` attribute, as you did with

```py
soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

you can [provide a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) that determines if the attribute of interest (in this case `href`) of any given tag *matches some desired pattern* like this:

```py
import re
from typing import Callable, Optional


def attr_matches(pattern: str) -> Callable[[Optional[str]], bool]:
    def filter_attribute(attr_value: Optional[str]) -> bool:
        if attr_value is None:
            return False
        return re.compile(pattern).search(attr_value) is not None
    return filter_attribute

...

tags = soup.find_all("a", href=attr_matches("/Company"))
```

Since `find_all` returns `Tag`s, a simple list comprehension will then get you just the `href` values:

```py
urls = [tag["href"] for tag in tags]
print(urls)
```

Output: `['/Company/apple-hospitality-reit-inc', '/Company/apple-inc', '/Company/maui-land-pineapple-co-inc', '/Company/pineapple-energy-inc']`

---

This generic approach is much more flexible because you can give this `attr_matches` function any valid [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) pattern and use it independent of what specific tag or attribute you want to filter by.

On the same web page for example, find all `<img>` tags, where the image source uri has `category` in it and ends with `webp`:

```py
tags = soup.find_all("img", src=attr_matches("category.+webp$"))
print([tag["src"] for tag in tags])
```

Output: `['/img/ar/category_premiumBadge.webp', '/img/ar/category_premiumBadge.webp', '/img/ar/category_premiumBadge.webp']`